# Nokogiri not wanting to read whole file

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing, nokogiri

The Ruby code:

```
require 'nokogiri'

f = open("doc2.xml")

# f.each { |line| puts line} # <-- works, so it's reading the whole file

@doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)

puts @doc.xpath("//2") # Nokogiri doesn't bother to get any nodes other than the first one.
```

The XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<1> T </1>

<2> U </2>

<3> V </3>
```

The output:

Yup, there's no output. I still have no idea why Nokogiri is only reading the first line of the document and then giving up. Is it incorrect XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is incorrect XML. There must be exactly one outer element:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<content>
    <1> T </1>
    <2> U </2>
    <3> V </3>
</content>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is literally my first time trying out XML to organize data and honestly didn't know this :) Thanks!